# fatal: protocol 'https' is not supported

Tags: laravel, git, github, git-push

Estoy intentando subir a GitHub un proyecto laravel pero al hacer push ocurre lo siguiente:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/Kmevi10/Tarjetas.git
$ git push origin master
fatal: protocol 'https' is not supported
```

Es un repositorio privado, no creo que este sea el fallo pero creo que proporcionar información nunca está de más.

Lo único que he hecho ha sido lo siguiente:

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel Tarjetas
$ cd Tarjetas
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "First commit"
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/Kmevi10/Tarjetas.git
$ git push origin master
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola kmevi. ¿Cómo has copiado la URL de github, con Ctrl + V?

Comment: Lo que @FerranMuñoz quiere decirte es que si estás tecleando eso a través de un terminal y pulsas `Control + V` es probable que hayas insertado un carácter invisible `^V` (código hexadecimal `16`). Es mejor volver a teclear esa instrucción y después usar el botón derecho del ratón y luego "Pegar".

Comment: Exactamente Oscar

Comment: Ya, investigando lo he sacado, he creado un repositorio nuevo para ejecutarlo por ahí y todo funciona correctamente hasta que hago el push a master que me sale lo siguiente: ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: puedes, por favor, responderte a ti mismo y marcar tu respuesta como respuesta aceptada en 48h?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema resuelto, el error está (como han dicho OscarGarcia y Ferran Muñoz en comentarios) a la hora de pegar la URL con Ctrl + V, ya que al hacer este atajo del teclado creas un carácter invisible ^V, la solución es dar Click derecho y pegar.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿en qué terminal y de qué sistema operativo aplica?, en Mac OS si se puede pegar con `cmd + v` y no hay problema de "caracteres invisibles".

Comment: Yo soy un usuario de linux y jamás he tenido problemas, pero en mi trabajo debo trabajar con Windows y en este S.O. sale este error y no sólo a mi, es muy común en usuarios de Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice @kmevi10 el problema es en Windows. Con PowerShell ponen en Propiedades y en Opciones de Edicion se encuentra "Utilizar Ctrl+Mays+V".